# Having trouble creating path to executable program in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I've been having a lot of trouble trying to set up a path to an executable file in linux.  Sorry If it's a dumb question, but I'm new to linux and still figuring things out.

Anyways, the file I want to create a path to is located at:

```
/opt/gitools/gitools-2.3.1/gitools
```

So I created a path at the end of my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gitools/gitools-2.3.1/
```

I've checked, and the file gitools as well as all parent directories are marked as executable.  However, when I enter "gitools", it returns:

```
/bin/bash: /opt/gitools/gitools-2.3.1/gitools: Permission denied
```

And when I enter "sudo gitools", it returns:

```
sudo: gitools: command not found
```

There is nothing wrong with the program itself, because I can run it by going to its directory and entering "sudo ./gitools", however, I'm unsure of why I need sudo when it should be executable for all users.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `chmod ugo+x /opt/gitools/gitools-2.3.1/gitools` perhaps? Though permission issues may extend to other files and directories, depending on what `gitools` and uses.

Comment: No, it's not that, gitools is already executable for all.  It wouldn't have anything to do with reading and writing permissions would it?

Comment: And running the full path without sudo, does that work?

Comment: What kind of executable file is `gitools`?

Comment: gitools is a 3rd part piece of software that is used to analyze biological data.  I know it requires java to run, but that's it.  the full path works with sudo, but not without it.

Comment: When I was making the directory in /opt/ I needed sudo to do that, so could it be a problem with /opt/'s permissions?

Comment: So is it a java file (in which case you may need to start it with java), or a script that starts java inside that script? Can you try `type /opt/gitools/gitools-2.3.1/gitools`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a java file, but it requires java to run according to teh website.  This is exactly what I'm trying to do from the website itself:

Comment: http://www.gitools.org/documentation/UserGuide_Installation.html#id6

Comment: Hey man thanks for all of your help!  I ended up getting it to work, apparently the directory was owned by root, and I needed to change the ownership to myself to get it to work.  Overall it was a great learning experience about permissions!

Comment: You understand why `sudo` failed right? You set the `PATH` for your **user** but that doesn't mean that `PATH` is preserved and will be used when executing a command by `sudo` unless you pass the `-E` option (which does preserve the user's environment) Take a look at `man 8 sudo`.

Comment: If the directory is owned by root, you shouldn't have to change the *owner* of the directory. You just need to make that directory (and parents) readable and executable by the world.

Comment: I assume you initially installed through root, and apparently, either your root's umask is strict, or the installation script that installed gittools is rather strict (and unhelpful).

Comment: You can answer your own question (and mark it solved) to finalise this question properly. Don't leave it open ended: comments are not supposed to be the answer (or the question).

Comment: David, I actually didn't know that sudo worked that way, but thank you, it's really good to know that for the future!  And Evert, for some reason my whole /opt directory is very strict.  I needed to use sudo to do all of the installation and deleting unnecessary files.  But good point about answering the question, I'm new and didn't realize I could answer my own.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution that works.

I tried to give full read write execute permission to all files in the program, but that just created errors that prevented running the program at all.

However, I noticed that the owner of all of the files was set to root, so in a last ditch attempt to get it to work I decided to recursively change the ownership of all directories and files associated with the program by going to the /opt directory and entering:

```
sudo chown -R myUsername:myUsername gitools/
```

Hope that this might help someone with a similar problem!